# Python exe on windows 2000: is not a valid win32 application

Tags: python, 32bit-64bit

I want to write a python program for a windows 2000 32-bit system.

For this program, I use the tk pack and the serial pack, because I want to create a connection for a machine.
I wrote a first test example and I convert this py-file into an exe-file.

On my main computer where I wrote the program, everything works fine.
But when I want to start this exe-file on the windows 2000 32-bit system, then I get the note:
is not a valid win32 application.

On my computer I use a 64 bit system but I convert it for a 32 bit system.
Everything should work but I get everytime the same error.

When I want to install everything on the win2000 system so I can write everything there, then I have problems with the pip package.

I do not know what I can do.

M

Comment: That's one of the reason why you should not convert python program to exe files ...

Comment: It's worth knowing that Python 3.4 and later [do not support Windows 2000](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0011/#id12)